# Como impedir que um usuário acesse ID de outro usuário na hora de editar post, fazendo alterações indevida?

Tags: php, laravel

Estava buscando uma forma do usuário logado não conseguir acessar outro post na hora de editar, apenas mudando o id na `url` e implementei algo assim, onde será adicionado no `Controller` que manipula os `posts`, `edit`, `update` etc...

Gostaria de saber se alguém já precisou implementar isso no Laravel e como fez, o código abaixo funciona pra mim, porém busco melhores práticas de implementação ou algo padrão do Laravel.

```
Route::get('post/{id}/edit', 'PostController@edit');
```

---

```
public function edit(postRegistro  $post, $id)
{    
    $idUserAutenticate = auth()->id();        
    $result = DB::table("post")
      ->whereRaw("id=$id and user_id=$idUserAutenticate")
      ->count();
    if ($result) {
        return view('users.postEdit', compact('post'));
    } else {
        return 'Ação não permitida!!';
    }
}
```

Comment: Você consegue esse nível de permissão facilmente de forma nativa no Laravel com [Policies e Gates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization)

Comment: Você pode utilizar o `Model`?

Comment: Tenho acesso total ao sistema, porém não muita experiência com laravel.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi você quer esse filtro do usuário seja dinâmico conforme o usuário que está logado? tipo o usuario 1 está logado e consequentemente só os registros que tem relação com o usuário 1 ele pode mexer?

Comment: Isso, verifiquei que quando edito um post aparece o id na url, ao mudar o id da url  e apertar enter, consegui editar um post de outro usuário.

Comment: Faz o curso de ACL da especializaTI vai te ajudar muito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Laravel conta com recursos de Autenticação.

Para isso você precisa rodar o seguinte comando do Artisan:

```
php artisan make:policie UserPolicy
```

Após isso você precisará definir quais serão as regras usando a Model User (em App\Policies\UserPolicy):

```
public function isAuthor(User $user, Post $post)
{
    return $user->id === $post->user_id;
}
```

*Esse exemplo é fictício, você precisará moldar melhor de acordo com seu código
Lembrando que esse caso supõe que suas tabelas User e Post estão relacionadas. Caso contrário veja sobre relacionamento no Eloquent ORM*.

Após isso você pode inserir a regra em seu controller ou na sua view.

Para colocar nos Controllers:

```
$this->authorize('isAuthor', User::class);
```

Código para inserir na view:

```
@can('isAdmin', Intranet\User::class)
    <!-- Código HTML -->
@endcan
```

Para maiores informações acesse a [documentação do Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization).